# Spring MVC pages are not accessible after adding mvc:resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resources

Structure:

[image: Structure]

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.javaguru.game"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

After adding mvc:resource tag I got access to my assets (here is everything fine, as it should be):
[image: Everything is fine]

But after that, if I trying to access my home page, it is not working anymore:
[image: Homepage is not working]

Where could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using spring 3. You need to add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
```

to run

```
<mvc:resources>
```

Could you try this?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it. game/home is working, but if I try game/ (my index page) it says: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/game/': {public java.lang.String com.javaguru.game.HelloController.printWelcome(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap), public java.lang.String com.javaguru.game.MainController.printWelcome(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)}

Comment: But as I see your exception, I saw that there are two different controller, hello and main controller. Is there any method directed path to /game/ in HelloContoller? This causes ambiguous.

Comment: I have updated picture of structure. I have only 1 controller.

Comment: I understood. I renamed controller today and seems spring was somewhere cached this name.. I rebuilt project now and everything working fine. Thanks a lot!